# Retag [mobile-web]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, meta

The tag [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) is a little redundant. There is no other `mobile-` prefixed tag, so the `web` suffix is unnecessary.

### My proposal

Rename [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) to [mobile](/questions/tagged/mobile), because, there is no other mobile platform for Stack Overflow, other than https://stackoverflow.com/ on the web.

Comment: I feel like this is more of a preference thing. I'm not sure the `-web` suffix is adding any confusion or really causing any problems at all, and it's still a functionally correct way to describe the topic.

Comment: *...there is no other mobile platform for Stack Overflow...* There were Android and iOS apps at one point. I don't see a problem with the tag being clear that it's specifically for the mobile site and not the mobile apps..

Comment: @BSMP There were? I didn't know that. There are no tags for them, though.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 [meta-tag:android-app] and [meta-tag:ios-app]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [mobile-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-web) tag refers to the mobile version of Stack Overflow. Not the current responsive full site on mobile, but the mobile site. The tag wiki makes this abundantly clear:

> For questions about the mobile version/theme of Stack Overflow.

To get to the mobile version of the site, you can click on "Mobile" button on the site footer. Given that the tag makes complete sense in the way it was intended, there is no need to retag/remove the [mobile-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-web) tag.